# spring persistence xml

Tags: spring, hibernate

What is the difference between:

persistenc.xml can be configured with hibernate properties OR Javax.persistence properties.

What scenarios would you use either one.

I tried using javax.persistence but my spring app would not work.. changed it to hibernate and it started working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

javax.persistence is the standard. Hibernate is an implementation. If you are completely sure that your DB layer will always be handled by Hibernate, go ahead and configure using Hibernate. If not, use javax.persistence, so that you could change your DB layer in the future.